# Drawer opens with 50% scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vue-composition-api

So I am using Vuejs to make an admin panel, and one of the things i'm creating now is a drawer that shows the preview of how this content will look on mobile. The bug is that when i open this drawer, it's always scrolled 50% for no reason.... anyone got any idea, please help. :/
[Here's how it opens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRF8b.jpg)

```
<el-drawer
  size="25%"
  :with-header="false"
  @closed="clearSideBar"
>
  <div class="author-preview">
    // the content is here
  </div>
</el-drawer>
```

clearSideBar is just a function that clears the drawer.
here's the css:

```
  .author-preview {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
```

Comment: If you need any more resources please let me know :/

Comment: i don't know if it's a bug with the framework or your code but if your search yields no result, you can use a fix in your "onDrawerOpen" callback to force the drawer to scroll to the top with [element.scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo)

Comment: i am forcing it with scrollTop, but it resets right away...

Comment: could you share the code of the `el-drawer` component?